# How do i fix the angle of my mathematical triangle of squares?

Tags: java

I need to fix my output as shown at the bottom, i have code that outputs the correct math values
but it does not output the correct angle that is expected of the example output that i have provided below. ( I know this is pretty simple for most of you stack users but im a beginner in java and this is something that confuses me ). I have not come up with any ideas on what i can do to fix this issue and put in the correct angle.

Instructions:

```
-Write a program using a Scanner that asks the user for a number
 n between 1 and 9 (inclusive).  
-The program prints a triangle with n rows.  
-The first row contains only the square of 1, and it is right-justified.  
-The second row contains the square of 2 followed by the square of 1, 
and is right justified.  
-Subsequent rows include the squares of 3, 2, and 1, and then 4, 3, 2 
 and 1, and so forth until n rows are printed.


 Assuming the user enters 4, the program prints the following triangle to the console



          1
       4  1
    9  4  1
16  9  4  1
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 9 inclusive:");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1 ; i <=n; i++) {
        for (int j = n-i; j >=1; j--) {
            System.out.print("");
        }
        for (int k = i; k <= n; k++ ) {
            System.out.print("  " + i * i);
        }
        System.out.println("  ");
    }
    scan.close();
}
}
```

My output:

```
Please enter a number between 1 and 9 inclusive:  4

  1  1  1  1  
  4  4  4  
  9  9  
  16
```

Comment: I have no solution, but from your example result and the fact that the largest number has just 2 digits you should format all numbers with 2 characters width (i.e. a leading space when < 10) and 1 space as a separator. And to right-justify a string you can use String.format("%15s", string) where 15 is the total width (which you can calculate from n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short and simple variant.

```
    for (int row = 1; row <= n; row ++) {
        for (int col = n; col >= 1; col--) {
            if (col <= row) {
                System.out.print(String.format("%2d ", col * col));
            } else {
                System.out.print("   ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Here is the output generated for input 9:

```
                         1 
                      4  1 
                   9  4  1 
               16  9  4  1 
            25 16  9  4  1 
         36 25 16  9  4  1 
      49 36 25 16  9  4  1 
   64 49 36 25 16  9  4  1 
81 64 49 36 25 16  9  4  1
```

Comment: I have to say, I prefer this.

Comment: I agree @sleepToken but my professor would prob consider your example with a nest of for loops instead of adding an if else statement.

Comment: I know what if statements are, i use them every week with python. I was just thinking of writing the code differently and i have.

Comment: When i ran yours somehow it did not print the correct calculations but not i got it to work and i added a while loop with it, the code i published also works just not past 9 and its a little funky lol. @Ridcully thx for the help

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR;** Use a pen and paper for annoying logic problems.

The easiest way to do a problem like this is to write out the locations you're printing in terms of the variables you are iterating through. An extra variable, `col` helps us keep track of the current column opposite of the direction we are iterating from.

We can notice that the number just corresponds to the column position, squared, if we were counting columns from right to left.

We can also notice that the number of blank spaces is equal to `n` - one less than the current row iteration (since that starts at 0).

```
          1 
       4  1 
    9  4  1 
16  9  4  1
```

All of that nonsense aside, we can use `String.format()` to make the output even for double digit numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 9 inclusive:");
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        int col = 4;

        // Print spaces
        for (int j = 0; j < (i-1); j++) {
            System.out.print("   ");
            col--;
        }

        // Print numbers
        for (int j = (i-1); j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(String.format("%2d", col*col) + " ");
            col--;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that really explains it very well. I was getting a lot of things confused and mixed up but the way you coded it makes it much easier to understand what is being done.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the code you guys provided and it had some logical issues when inputting a number past 4 it would not square the triangle correctly and would only create the shape. I have solved the issue by adding a while loop and editing the for loops and not it outputs correctly.

Incorrect output:

```
Please enter a number between 1 and 9 inclusive: 8

                      9 
                   4  9 
                1  4  9 
             0  1  4  9 
          1  0  1  4  9 
       4  1  0  1  4  9 
    9  4  1  0  1  4  9 
16  9  4  1  0  1  4  9
```

Correct Code Given:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageGrades {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 9 inclusive:");
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    for (int row = 1; row <= n; row ++) {
        for (int col = n; col >= 1; col--) {
            if (col <= row) {
                System.out.print(String.format("%2d ", col * col));
            } else {
                System.out.print("   ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

}
```

My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriangleTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Number between 1 and 9 : ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    while(n < 0 || n > 9)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a valid value between 1 and 9 :");
        n = scan.nextInt();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        for(int j = 0; j <= n*2-(i + i); j++)
        {

            System.out.print("  ");
        }

        for(int l = i + 1; l > 0; l--)
        {
            int r = l*l;
            System.out.print(r +  "  ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");

    }
    scan.close();
}

}
```

Correct Output:

```
Enter Number between 1 and 9 : 10
Please enter a valid value between 1 and 9 :9

                                1  

                             4  1  

                          9  4  1  

                      16  9  4  1  

                  25  16  9  4  1  

              36  25  16  9  4  1  

          49  36  25  16  9  4  1  

      64  49  36  25  16  9  4  1  

  81  64  49  36  25  16  9  4  1
```

Comment: The output of my solution is correct. Even more so than your's, as your's has more spaces between the numbers than the original example has :-P But it is good that you're doing it on your own and not just copying some answer code without thinking about it.